# DNS - Default to an IP when host name fails to resolve?

Tags: domain-name-system

Is it possible to setup some DNS server where it will default to an IP address if the the host name it tries to resolve fails to resolve?  I'm having a problem where a host name is intermittently failing to resolve.

Comment: I'd suggest you're far better off dealing with the existing problem, DNS hacks will cause you a lot of pain down the line. Also, I'm not sure it's possible to set yourself up as authoritative for `example.com`, but only when example.com's name servers are off line.  A temporary workaround could be to add a static entry to client `hosts` files while the NS is unreliable.

Comment: I concur with SmallClanger, you should fix the real problem. Maybe you can port here the problem and maybe we can help fix it.

Comment: I'm using PayPal and am getting intermittent host name resolve failures.  I'm not sure if this is isolated to our network or if it's specific to PayPal.  A Google search has suggested other shared similar problems, but in the past.  We are still experiencing it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of NSlookup? What are you using for a local DNS server? Who do you forward to? Have you cleared your cache (both server side and client side)?

Depending on the error with NSlookup, try specifying a different server - maybe Google's DNS servers 8.8.8.8 an see if there is a difference.

also more details about what you are trying to do when you start having problems would be helpful..